# What is the difference between dynamic.partition=True and dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Spark 2.0 - pyspark

I seen the following 2 properties paired. What is the difference between them?

```
 hive> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
 hive> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=non-strict;
```

I know what the outcome is when they are used - you can use dynamic partitioning to load/create multiple partitions, but I don't know the difference between these two similar commands.

When I was running this code

```
input_field_names=['id','code','num']
df \
.select(input_field_names) \
.write \
.mode('append')\
.insertInto('test_insert_into_partition')
```

I got an error message that says `Dynamic partition strict mode requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict`

Using `spark.sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict")` the code works. It doesn't require me to use the other one.

Why don't I need to set `SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;` and what else should I know to choose which one to use.

Comment: so, I know that you need both of them, but the question really is why do you need both of them. What does one do that the other does not, or is the bottom one overriding the top one and so you just need the one

Comment: You need both of them because, err, they do different things?

Comment: I am going to update the answer tomorrow.

Comment: I think I have answered the question even more fully now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is much to google, here is a short answer.

If you want to insert dynamically into Hive partitions both values need to be set and you can then load many partitions in one go:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict

create table tblename (h string,m string,mv double,country string)partitioned by (starttime string) location '/.../...'

INSERT overwrite table tblename PARTITION(starttime) SELECT h,m,mv,country,starttime from tblename2
```

Otherwise you need to do like this, setting the partition col val yourself / explicity:

```
INSERT into table tblename PARTITION(starttime='2017-08-09') SELECT h,m,mv,country from tblname2 where to_date(starttime)='2017-08-09'
```

> The purpose of default value of 'strict' for
>   **hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode** is there to prevent a user from
>   accidentally overwriting all the partitions, i.e. to avoid data loss.

So, there is not a situation of difference, rather a situation of caution, a but like the safety catch on a firearm, as it were.